# google maps API3 drawing custom map icon based on user selection

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Im working on a google maps plugin (there's always room for another right?) and I'm drawing a preview of the map my users will be inserting into their content. Im able to draw everything I set out to, custom content in the info window, setting the location (through `places.Autocomplete`) etc. The one thing that is escaping me is custom map icon isn't being drawn.

My goal is to have the default icon drawn on first load, and then update it when it changes

Im not getting any 404 or errors in the console, and I've checked my event handlers and they are all working. Can anyone tell me where I've going astray?

Here is what I have so far:

```
//Initilize the map
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function initialize(infowindow) {

    var init_center = new google.maps.LatLng(43.703793, -72.326187);
    mapOptions = {
      center: init_center,
      zoom: parseFloat(mapZoomReturn),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      scrollwheel : false,
    };
    var input = document.getElementById('mapAddress');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    //var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    //  position: init_center,
    //  map: map, 
    //  icon: mapMarkerImageReturn  
    //});

    // Draw the map 
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
            // marker needs to be set after the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: init_center,
        map: map, 
        icon: mapMarkerImageReturn  
    });     

    // Set up event listeners

    // Info window DOM->MAP
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('mapInfoWindow'),
        'change', function() {
        mapInfoWindowReturn = escape(jQuery('#mapInfoWindow').val());
        // get the extra content from feild, by this time the place_changed even will have fired at least once, so we have these values
        infowindowPlace = get_info_bubble(locIcon, locName, locAddress, locPhone, locWeb, mapInfoWindowReturn); // returns formatted markup for info bubble
        infowindow.setContent(infowindowPlace);
    });

    // Marker dropdown selection DOM->MAP
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('mapMarker'), 'change', update_maker);
    // Custom marker text field DOM->MAP
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('mapMarkerImage'), 'change', update_maker );

    function update_maker(){
        //update the marker imge - (not working)
        markerImage = get_marker_image(); // returns URL as string
        marker.setIcon(markerImage);
        marker.setPosition(locPlace.geometry.location);
        marker.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        infowindowPlace = get_info_bubble(locIcon, locName, locAddress, locPhone, locWeb, mapInfoWindowReturn);
        infowindow.close();
        if (mapMarkerImageReturn !=='' || mapMarkerImageReturn !== false) marker.setVisible(false);
            input.className = '';
            locPlace = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!locPlace.geometry) {
        // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
            input.className = 'notfound';
        return;
        }
        // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
        if (locPlace.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(locPlace.geometry.viewport);
            mapCurrCenter = map.getCenter();
        } else {
            map.setCenter(locPlace.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(parseFloat(mapZoomReturn));
            mapCurrCenter = map.getCenter();
        }

        // Set the marker image (not working)
        markerImage = get_marker_image(); // returns URL as string
        marker.setIcon(markerImage);
        marker.setPosition(locPlace.geometry.location);
        marker.setMap(map);

        // get the location values for the info bubble 
        if (locPlace.address_components) {
            //console.log(locPlace.address_components);
            // Populate values for info bubble
            locName = locPlace.name;
            locIcon = locPlace.icon;
            locAddress = locPlace.formatted_address;
            locPhone    = locPlace.formatted_phone_number;
            locWeb = locPlace.website;
        }
        infowindowPlace = get_info_bubble(locIcon, locName, locAddress, locPhone, locWeb, mapInfoWindowReturn);
        infowindow.setContent(infowindowPlace);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Comment: What is "mapMarkerImageReturn"

Comment: Is the default icon showing correctly? Is your function returning the right URL? try removing `marker.setMap(map)`, if the icon is already on the map you just need to update the icon and position

Comment: `mapMarkerImageReturn` is the value of the current icon as a string, and it's coming though just fine

Comment: @koala_dev a defult icon isn't showing just the infowindow . . . taking out `marker.setMap(map)` isn't making any difference it seems. I think there's a conflict with how I'm building the infowindow and how the marker is set.

Comment: Try changing the order of the marker initialization and the map constructor, that is, create the marker after creating the map

Comment: @ koala_dev thanks for looking at this. Your sugestion is a step in the right direction, and I've updated the code in the question.Moving the marker after the map does establish the marker on window load, and it will respond to the dom listener for `mapMarker` when selcetion is changed - so hooray there. But it only works *before* the address autocomplete listener fires, afterward the icon is lost.... grrrr

Comment: A link to your map would make this much easier to debug.

Comment: Turns out I'm going about changing the marker in the `autocomplete` listener all wrong. I assumed the marker was already there, but its not, I need to redefine it i.e. `marker = new google.maps.Marker({....` and it works as expected.